# Encontrar Valores unicos de una columna con el maximo valor en otra

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

como estan??

necesito generar una tabla que muestre que marcas pagan mas 'Valor_Neto'' SIN REPETIR LA MARCA... del siguiente DF.. porfas amigos

[[image: dataframe experimental1]

---

te amo bro, soy nuevo en esto..
me podrias decir los pasos que hiciste?

logro ver que:

1. create una nueva_df dond agrupaste 'VALOR_NETO y Marca. me perdí para que usaste el max() y el reset_index() al final.
2. Usaste sort_values para ordenarla, pero no comprendo para que es ignore_index=True, inplace=True)

muchas gracias broder!

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar algo como esto si quieres el máximo valor neto de cada marca:

```
nueva_df = df.groupby(by='Marca')['Valor_Neto'].max().reset_index()
nueva_df.sort_values(by='Valor_Neto', ascending=False, ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
print(nueva_df)
```

`.groupby` agrupa los datos por marca pero no hace nada con el group sino hasta que le pasas `.max()`.

`.max()` le dice a pandas que quieres el valor máximo de cada grupo que creaste.

`.reset_index()` es para que después de calcular el máximo de cada grupo pandas ponga el nombre del grupo (la marca) como columna en `nueva_df`.

`sort_values` es solo para que las marcas con mayor valor neto máximo aparezcan primero.

`ignore_index=True` es casi casi "para que se vea bonito" el índice (para que empiece desde 0).

`inplace=True` es para que haga los cambios ahí mismo en `nueva_df` en vez de crear otra df.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. Aunque la respuesta pueda solucionar el problema, la pregunta no cumple con los requisitos mínimos de la comunidad. Responder a preguntas que no muestran un intento por parte del autor incentivan la holgazanería.